# google sheets: use regexmatch to filter literal question mark character

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I match a literal question mark character in a REGEXMATCH formula in a Google Sheets Custom Formula filter?
I am trying the below to omit rows that have "na" or "?" in column E, but it filters out ALL rows... I have already tried escaping the question mark with a tilde, as well as 1,2,3,4, and 5 backslashes, to no avail. Greatly appreciate any help!

```
=not(regexmatch(E:E, "na|?"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out: a single backslash **does** work in the above formula. I was confused because I was not getting anything at all, but in reading about regexmatch, I found it only works on text-formatted cells, so I had to modify it using the "T()" formula to convert column E to text before evaluation. The following now works for me:

```
=not(regexmatch(T(E:E), "na|\?"))
```